# Append Partial View as string using Response.Filter interferes with Visual Studio browser link

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, action-filter

I'm trying to append som UI tools automatically using an action filter like this:

```
public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext) {
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && !DisableEditorTools) {
        using (var sw = new StringWriter()) {
            filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model = filterContext.RouteData.GetCurrentPage<IPage>();
            ViewEngineResult viewResult =
                ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext,
                    "~/Areas/UI/Views/Shared/_UIControls.cshtml");
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View,
                filterContext.Controller.ViewData, filterContext.Controller.TempData, sw);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
            viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
            HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
            response.Filter = new AddUiToolsFilter(response.Filter, sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString());
        }
    }
    else {
        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

And then I'm trying to rewrite the response stream like this

```
public class AddUiToolsFilter : MemoryStream
{
    private readonly Stream _response;
    private readonly string _htmlToAppend;
    public AddUiToolsFilter(Stream response, string htmlToAppend)
    {
        _response = response;
        _htmlToAppend = htmlToAppend;
    }
    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        var html = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        html = AddUiTools(html, _htmlToAppend);
        buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);
        _response.Write(buffer, offset, buffer.Length);
    }
    private string AddUiTools(string html, string htmlToAppend)
    {
        string newHtmlDocument = html.Replace("</body>", htmlToAppend + "</body>");
        return newHtmlDocument;
    }
}
```

This works pretty good when I not using a browser on my dev machine and this is because Visual studio has something they call browser link. I know it is possible to turn off this but is it possible to make sure that my action filter doesn't interfere with Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I've had the same issue for ages and I finally fixed it and the solution might help someone out.

The problem seems to stem from the fact the buffer length is not the same as the count parameter. Instead of doing the html manipulation in the write method, I instead write the buffer into the base memory stream and then make my changes when the stream is closing:

```
public class AddUiToolsFilter : MemoryStream
{
    private readonly Stream _response;
    private readonly string _htmlToAppend;

    public AddUiToolsFilter(Stream response, string htmlToAppend)
    {
        _response = response;
        _htmlToAppend = htmlToAppend;
    }

    public override void Close()
    {
        var html = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base.ToArray());

        // Add your UI Tools
        string newHtmlDocument = html.Replace("</body>", _htmlToAppend + "</body>");

        byte[] rawResult = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(newHtmlDocument);
        _response.Write(rawResult, 0, rawResult.Length);
        _response.Close();
    }
}
```

Thinking about it, Flush() might be a technically better place to put it, but you'd have to potentially deal with an early flush.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to run the `base.OnResultExecution` always when you are not returning a custom response.

```
public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext) {
    if (!DisableUiTools) {
        using (var sw = new StringWriter()) {
            filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model = filterContext.RouteData.GetCurrentPage<IPage>();
                var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext, "~/Areas/UI/Views/Shared/_UIControls.cshtml");
                var viewContext = new ViewContext(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, filterContext.Controller.ViewData, filterContext.Controller.TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
                viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
                var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
                response.Filter = new AddUiToolsFilter(response.Filter, sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString());
            }
        }
    }else
        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
}
```

Comment: That didn't make any difference, the only workaround I have is to turn of the Browser link